# YTPlayerView does not play Content on Simulator (Decoding failed with error code)

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, ios-simulator

When I play a normal content, it loads perfectly fine on 
the simulator.

YTPlayerView parameters

```
@implementation SingleVideoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString *videoId = @"weRHyjj34ZE";

  // For a full list of player parameters, see the documentation for the HTML5 player
  // at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5
  NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
      @"controls" : @0,
      @"playsinline" : @1,
      @"autohide" : @1,
      @"showinfo" : @0,
      @"modestbranding" : @1
  };
  self.playerView.delegate = self;
  [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:videoId playerVars:playerVars];



  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(receivedPlaybackStartedNotification:)
                                               name:@"Playback started"
                                             object:nil];

}
```

But, If I have a HD Video in my playlist it gives below error and the code https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Code is available with the Git Project, just download it and change the videoId in the SingleVideoViewController.

```
Decoding failed with error code -1
Decoding: C0 0x01E00168 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 6668
Options: 1x-1 [0000002D,01E0010F] 0001C060
Decoding failed with error code 7
Decoding: C0 0x01E00168 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 773
Options: 1x-1 [0000002D,01E0010F] 0001C060
Decoding failed with error code -1
Decoding: C0 0x01E00168 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 773
Options: 480x360 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 0001C060
```

Comment: What is the url that you are playing? It might be corrupt.

Comment: I have a play list which I am trying to play. One video I have uploaded which works fine, other one I added from the YOU TUBE Video id weRHyjj34ZE

Comment: Show the code that you have used to configure the player.

Comment: I have not written a new code, project example is available on GitHub , in SingleViewController just change the video id.

Comment: Added the answer. You can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **`origin`** parameter to your `playerVars` `dictionary`, i.e

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
      @"controls" : @0,
      @"playsinline" : @1,
      @"autohide" : @1,
      @"showinfo" : @0,
      @"modestbranding" : @1,
      @"origin":@"https://www.youtube.com"
  };
```

From `YouTube` API docs,

> **Origin:** This parameter provides an extra security measure for the IFrame API and is only supported for IFrame embeds. If you are using
>   the IFrame API, which means you are setting the enablejsapi parameter
>   value to 1, you should always specify your domain as the origin
>   parameter value.

You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en).

Comment: Adding Origin worked. For some videos, it requires Origin.I think it is required for few videos, whether its HD or not. Any idea which setting for Video upload asks for it?

Comment: What setting are you looking for while uploading the video?